# My custom module suddenly stopped appearing in the admin panel and in app/etc/config.php

Tags: magento2.3.3

I'm in development stage and I have a custom module that used to be showing up in the admin panel. 
Yesterday it suddenly stopped showing up in this panel. 
I don't see my custom module in `app/etc/config.php`, which sounds like it's not being built.
I removed the custom module from my VSCode solution. Then I added it back in and ran from terminal, `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
When running this command it shows me all the modules its updating and mine is not listed.

**`magento-store/src/app/code/Cellularisrael/Mobileplans/registration.php`**

```
 <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Cellularisrael_Mobileplans',
__DIR__
 );
```

**`magento-store/src/app/code/Cellularisrael/Mobileplans/etc/module.xml`**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Cellularisrael_Mobileplans" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
</module>
</config>
```

Comment: please add code of `registration.php` and `module.xml`

Comment: did you try to remove it in `setup_module` table as well?

Comment: No I did not. Can you please guide me as to the correct steps to take for that as I am new to Magento. Thank you

Comment: I deleted it from this table but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my issue ended up being related to the docker container that I was using to run my code. 
Something was being cached. When I restarted my computer and then restarted the container everything seemed to be working correctly and my module is showing up once again in the admin panel!